# White spots on succelent

Tags: houseplants, succulents

I have had this succulent for the last year. Bought it a farmers market. It has always been inside at a north facing window.

I have repotted and it seemed to do better. But it now has these white spots. I am able to clean with a wet tissue, scrape them off. It has never really flourished, but it does have new growth. Does it need more sun? What are the spots and what should I do to treat it? I searched online and could not find anything. One video hinted it could be mineral deposits? 
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIXFe.jpg)
Thanks[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: the spots come off if prodded lightly?

Comment: Looks like scale or mealybugs, try to wipe them off carefully. North facing windows seems not the right place for flourishing plants.

Comment: Stephie, yes they do come off. B.nota - I don’t think it is mealybugs ( seen pics of it online ). Yeah I moved it to a sunnier part of the house.

Comment: Did you also find pics of scale? [Here](https://succulentplantcare.com/help-there-are-insects-on-my-succulents/) for example.

Comment: Thanks b.nota, yes does look like that. Thanks a ton! Will try the neem oil treatment mentioned in it.

Comment: What soil is in this pot?  It is a bit too large for your succulent, holds too much water and your succulent has a very small, shallow root system.  Your plant is stressed and that leaves it vulnerable to insects such as mealy bug. I would transplant into a 4 to 6" clay pot wider than tall using only sterilized potting soil. Don't put any mulch or chips or sand or rocks or anything else in to that pot other than soil.  Your plant is too small for this pot.  Neem will take care of the mealy bug or scale but the problem is a stressed plant, too much water, not enough light.  A south window?

Comment: I think the soil is succulent/citrus potting soil, I think it might have some orchid bark mix, because I was running out of regular soil. I have moved it to a south facing window and cleaned the scales with water and bio degradable soap mixture. Good point about smaller pot, did not think about that. Will also move to a smaller pot. Thanks a ton!